# Attribute error using Pydot to create a graph

Tags: graphviz, pydot

I am using IPython on Windows10 to train and draw out a decision tree. I know the following code worked on linux some time back. I installed pydot and also have graphviz (with the path correctly specified).

```
# Train and draw out a decision tree

from IPython import display
from sklearn import datasets, tree, utils
from sklearn.externals.six import StringIO  
import pydot 

# Train a small decision tree on the iris dataset
dataset = datasets.load_iris()
X_iris, y_iris = utils.shuffle(dataset.data, dataset.target,random_state=42)
tree_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3).fit(X_iris, y_iris)

# Generate a plot of the decision tree
dot_data = StringIO() 
tree.export_graphviz(tree_clf, out_file=dot_data) 
graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue()) 
display.Image(graph.create_png())
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-3452aa5e9794> in <module>()
     15 tree.export_graphviz(tree_clf, out_file=dot_data)
     16 graph = pydot.graph_from_dot_data(dot_data.getvalue())
---> 17 display.Image(graph.create_png())

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'create_png'
```

Comment: Please format your output so that it is readable

Comment: I have removed the unformatted text - It was just the value contained in dot_data.getvalue() and might not be relevant at this point

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by changing all the `pydot` command into `pydotplus`.(including `import pydotplus`)It may be possible use `!pip install pydotplus` to install pydotplus package.

Reference
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/7342/files

Comment: Yeah, in python 3.5 this was the only way to fix the issue. Thanks!